# Shared object dynamic library file not showing as white and not as green

Tags: shared-libraries, ls, dynamic-library

I have a directory with some shared libraries. My understanding is the shared libraries should appear as light blue (if it's pointing to another shared library) or green. In the below image (produced using `ls`), the `libmetis.so` shared library is white. Coincidentally, I appear to be having some issues with detecting some of the functions within this library when I try to link the code I am compiling with `libmetis.so`, so I am wondering if this has to do with `libmetis.so` showing up as white.

What are the implications of this dynamic library showing up as white?

ls output showing green and white shared object files

[image: ls output showing green and white shared object files]

Output of `LS_COLORS`:

```
rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
```

[Output of `ls -l`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iP0T.png)

Comment: Show the command you were using, and show the setting of `LS_COLORS`.

Comment: I edited the OP to show the output of of `echo $LS_COLORS`. The command I used to generate the image in the OP was just `ls` without any flags.

Comment: So you didn't get my hint: Show the output of `ls -l`! The color has only meaning to human users, helping to see different types.

Comment: Ohh, I uploaded the output of `ls -l` in the OP. Or you can reference this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iP0T.png

Comment: `libmetis.so` isn't executable; maybe that makes the difference.

Comment: Hmmm, good point. Do we need to be making dynamic libraries executable? I'm not too familiar with how this works. So the other day I was having issues with having CMake automatically find this dynamic library during the linking process. I wonder if that was because it wasn't executable. I worked around that by manually adding this dynamic library into the linking process. My code is running fine, even though `libmetis.so` is still not executable. That seems to suggest that you don't need to make a dynamic library executable if you want to use it at run time?

Comment: Actually I'm unsure, but you can compare the permission bits of a shared library that displays in the correct colors with those who do not. Independent of the color issue with ls, I would suggest to set the permission bits the same as the standard system libraries' permissions.